# convert curl command to a Python request command

Tags: python, curl

I am trying to convert the following `curl` command to `Python` request command:

```
curl 'https://api.test.com/v1/data/?type=name&status=active' -H 'Authorization: apikey username:api_key_value'
```

I have tried a lot of possible solutions like the one below but nothing is working and I am getting a'401' code:

```
url = "https://api.test.com/v1/data/?type=name&status=active"
headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8"}
params = (
(username, api_key_value),
)
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Params specifies the URL parameters.  The Authorization thing is just another header.  And `response.json` is a function.

```
url = "https://api.test.com/v1/data/"
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8",
    "Authorization": "apikey {0}:{1}".format(username, api_key_value)
}
params = { 'type': 'name', 'status': 'active' }
data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
print(data)
```

Comment: You Rock! Thank you so much for the answer and the explanation!! :)